# Попап с кнопкой Like Facebook

Tags: html, css, javascript

Всем здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, примеры как можно реализовать данный плагин: при нажатии на Like вылетает это белое попап окно как на этом сайте.
http://www.skinjay.com/

[image]

Comment: Можно использоваться [bootstrap](http://bootstrap-ru.com/javascript.php#popovers)

Comment: А сюда: data-content="" можно вставлять код плагина? А есть ли какие-то другие способы не только twitter bootstrap?

Comment: Таких плагинов на самом деле тонны, просто bootstarp бесплатен и предоставляет простую реализацию, погуглите и не забывайте про лицензию.